# Как построить систему уведомлений в распределенном проекте?

Tags: websocket, уведомления, push-уведомления

Я знаю что для уведомлений с сервера на клиент нужно использовать WebSockets или Long pooling или еще что-то похожее. Но как уведомить одного пользователя о новом сообщении когда ему совсем другой пользователь прислал сообщение. А, другой пользователь может находиться на другом сервере или же даже в другом дата центре.
Допустим сценарий:
Пользователь Петя открыл  WebSocket соединение с сервером в Европейском дата центре.
Пользователь Джордж открыл  WebSocket соединение с сервером в Американском дата центре.

Петя отправляет Джорджу новое сообщение, и Джордж с не большой задержкой получает его.

Как правильно это реализовать?
У меня есть несколько идей, но я не уверен какое из них нужно выбрать. Возможно это делаться вообще по другому. Куда копать нужно?

**Идея №1**
Когда любой пользователь открывает connection, то мы записываем в распределенную базу данных информацию. Типа: user_id → server_address. server_address – это адрес сервера где он открыл WebSocket.
Так как информация не велика то, всю эту информацию можно держать в RAM. Допустим, можно сделать Redis или Memcached кластер с репликациями и twemproxy который будет работать с кластером. Или использовать готовый кластер от Redis. Также можно заодно еще дополнительную информацию держать там. Допустим пользователь online или offline.

Когда Петя будет отправлять Джорджу сообщение, то мы будем лезть в Redis, смотреть ip сервера Джорджа и на прямую отправлять это сообщение на сервер Джорджа. Сервер Джорджа будет принимать сообщение и отправлять Джорджу через WebSocket.

При этом можно сделать кеш кешей. Логично что к одному серверу будут подключены одни пользователи, которые будут отправлять сообщения своим друзьям и еще кому-то. При отправке сообщений можно будет кешировать адреса тех пользователей, а в случае неудачи инвалидировать кеш. Но это уже преждевременная оптимизация, наверное.

**Идея №2**
Я пока не понял как именно данные будут распределяться и обрабатываться. Но, там можно создать подписчиков и продюсеров и поставить фильтры которые будут фильтровать сообщения и отправлять нужным продюсерам. Не понял я из-за фильтров. Непонятно как они будут это все проверять и как правильно их писать.
Как я понимаю этот вариант лучше, если в нем разобраться, так как можно хранить также данные в RAM и на прямую с Apache Ignite отправлять сообщения на нужный нам сервер (наверное, но не факт). При этом количество коннекшенов API серверов будет на много меньше. В первом случае у нас будет N * (N-1) коннекшенов, а во втором N, где N это количество серверов.

**Идея №3**
Такая же, как идея №1, но вместо того чтобы на прямую отправлять сообщение мы будет отправлять его в очередь. В каждом дата центре будет свой локальный RabbitMQ кластер. При том  каждый сервер создаст в RabbitMQ кластере свою очередь и подпишется на неё. Когда мы захотим передать сообщение от Пети к Джорджу, мы посмотрим к какому дата центру принадлежит данный IP. Если к локальному то в зависимости от сервера отправим сообщение в соответствующую очередь. Если в другом дата центре, то отправим сообщение в тот дата центр и там любой сервер сможет отправить это сообщение в локальный кластер RabbitMQ. В таком случае у нас будет N*2 + N*(M-1) конекшенов где N – количество серверов, M – количество дата центров.

Как правильно создать данную систему уведомлений? Возможно все мои идеи не правильны и есть более проработанные схемы.

Comment: по websocket можно подключиться к любому серверу , и можно сделать подключение к нескольким серверам одновременно. поэтому проще назначить один сервер для обмена сообщениями и работать через него

Comment: Это да, но это не будет работать в распределенном проекте, где много пользователей разбросаны по всему миру. Всех пользователей нельзя подключить к одному серверу.

Comment: почему нельзя? что сервер ляжет? при работе через websocket нагрузка на сервер минимальная. и нет ограничения на количество подключений.

Comment: Да, сервер ляжет. При выполнении медленных заданий сервер не будет успевать справляться с нагрузкой. Если мы под каждого пользователя будем создавать поток на выполнение задания, то мы будем тратить очень много времени на переключение потоков при процессорном разделении времени, и сервер просто зависнет.

Comment: Если мы создадим пул потоков допустим на 200-400 потоков, то после того как пул забьется, наши пользователи начнут ожидать освобождения потоков. Так как пользователи будут часто приходить, а потоков всего 200-400 то через определенное время наш стек переполниться и все последующие конекшены начнут отваливаться.

Comment: При этом нельзя забывать о большом latency между континентами. Нельзя пользователей с Европы посылать в Американские сервера и наоборот. А то что у websocket минимальный overhead, я согласен. Это хорошо увеличивает пропускную способность, но это мало влияет на нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: это всё вымыслы , у ws преимущество - минимальная нагрузка на сервер. если нет передачи - сервер курит бамбук вне зависимости от количества подключений по ws.

Comment: В каком смысле вымыслы? Я говорю про те случаи, когда мощности одного сервера не достаточно. При этом нельзя забывать про SPOF.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47251/discussion-between--and-alexandr).